# WCF RIA Serices referencing another RIA Service class library

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I am getting an "ambiguous namespace" exception.  It is because I have mutiple RIA Services class libraries that reference other RIA Services class libraries.  Is it possible to only allow the code generated part of a RIA Services class library and not as a reference?

I don't want to create a monolithic RIA Services class library as our enterprise application has modules that only use certain pieces.  Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that my bin and obj folders were corrupt.  I Cleaned the solution and it started working again.  I did have to use the "Global" key word to get the application finally working.  I am not sure why I had to do it that way since I had a reference to the assembly but it now works.